# MongoDB repair issue

Tags: linux, mongodb, wiredtiger

> Repair command

**sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair**

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-20T18:05:11.071+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22350,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Data file is missing. Attempting to drop and re-create the collection.","attr":{"uri":"table:_mdb_catalog"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-20T18:05:11.071+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22353,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Rebuilding ident","attr":{"ident":"_mdb_catalog"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-20T18:05:11.072+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":-31803,"message":"[1647799511:72009][2120:0x7f6984658cc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __schema_source_config, 50: metadata information for source configuration \"file:_mdb_catalog.wt\" not found: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found"}}

"error":{"code":4,"codeName":"NoSuchKey","errmsg":"Unable to find metadata for table:_mdb_catalog"}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-20T17:55:17.150+00:00"}
```

> Mongo Start Command

**sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb**

"msg":"An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair."

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question